# Question about calculating the price of a coupon bond at different times: FM question.

Tags: solution-verification, finance, compound-interest

Let's say we are working with a coupon bond with face value of $F = 100€$, maturity of $T = 5$ years and with $10€$ coupons paid anually. Also, consider we're dealing with a continuously compounded interest rate of $r = 12\%.$ I tried to compute the price of this bond at the actual time and after $1$ year of its emission.

For the actual time, we have that

$$ B_c(0) = \sum_{i=1}^5 10e^{-i \cdot r}+ 100e^{-5r} = \sum_{i=1}^5 10e^{-i \cdot 0.12} + 100e^{-5 \cdot 0.12} \approx 90.27€ $$

and I believe that, for this case, my calculations are correct. My main problem comes when I try to compute the price of this bond after $1$ year.

My thought process was the following: after $1$ year, the coupon bound in question becomes a coupon bond with maturity in $4$ years, with annualy coupons of $10€$ and with the same interest rate and face value of the initial text. With this in mind, we directly have that

$$ B_c(1) = \sum_{i=1}^4 10e^{-i\cdot r} + 100e^{-4r} = \sum_{i=1}^4 10e^{-i\cdot 0.12} + 100e^{-4\cdot 0.12} \approx 91.78€$$

After these calculations, I started to wonder: does it really makes sense that a bond increases its price after $1$ year? And my intuition tells me that this shouldn't be the case since after $1$ year, we have lost one payment of coupons. So I think that I am doing something wrong in my calculations, but I can't figure what it is.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: After one year, you should consider the bond as a 4-year bond with annual coupon payments. However, you should also subtract the present value of the missed coupon payment that you didn't receive in the first year.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Mathxx . What would be the present value of the missed coupon payment ?

Comment: For the extreme case at the maturity, after the 5th coupon is paid, the bond would have a price $B_c(5)$ equal to the face value $100€$. This is a further increase from your $B_c(0)$ and $B_c(1)$.

Comment: @peterwhy Are you suggesting that my intuition is wrong and my calculations are correct?

Comment: The calculation is correct. Maybe you mixed up your intuition with a premium bond, for example try if instead the annual coupon is $20€$?

Comment: @peterwhy Well, the value of the coupon wouldn't change my intuition. Let's say a bank emits a bond and some person buys it. Then, if this person waits one year, receives the payment of one coupon and then decides to sell the bond, this same person would sell the bond for a higher price than it was initially purchased? Intuitevily, the next person who buys this bond is not going to receive the payment of all the coupons (since the first person already got paid the first coupon), so why should the bond be sold by a higher value after $1$ year?

Comment: Because the interest rate is higher. At year 0, instead of buying this bond with $90.27€$, the person can invest elsewhere with the $12\%$ continuous compounding rate. After one year, the second option gives $90.27€\cdot e^{0.12} = 101.78€$, which is a $11.51€$ interest on top of the deposit. This total is the same as in the first option, which gives only $10€$ coupon.

Comment: The above comment also explains why the bond is discounted in the first place. Otherwise, how come the bond is discounted initially, and a buyer can receive all the coupons and still receive a higher price at maturity (the face value)?

Comment: Rereading your comment, I expanded my answer regarding the apparent increase in bond price after 1 year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interest rate is higher than the coupon rate.

Consider investing from year 0 to year 1. The person with $90.27€$ can

- buy this bond, or
- invest elsewhere with the $12\%$ continuous compounding rate instead.

After one year, the second option gives $90.27€\cdot e^{0.12} = 101.78€$, which is a $11.51€$ interest on top of the initial investment. This total is the same as in the first option, which gives only $10€$ coupon.

In a slightly different interpretation, while paying $90.27€$ for the bond at emission is a lower price than paying $91.78€$ one year later, the first is in fact a higher cost, because $90.27€$ at $t=0$ should worth $90.27€\cdot e^{0.12} = 101.78€$ at $t=1$. The difference is exactly $101.78€ - 91.78€ = 10€$ in $t=1$ value: the missed coupon.

For the extreme case at the maturity, after the 5th coupon is paid, the bond would have a price $B_c(5)$ equal to the face value $100€$. This is a further increase from your $B_c(0)$ and $B_c(1)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have only one further question (that it's not directly related to the issue you solved for me): let's say we have a bond with maturity in $T$ years, that pays an anual coupon $c$ and that has some continuously compounded interest rate $r$ and some face value $F$. If I want to compute the price of this bond at time $t$ (expressed in years) is the formula below always valid? $$ B_c(t) = \sum_{i=1}^{T-t} ce^{-i \cdot r} + Fe^{T-t}.$$ I am mainly concerned about the exponent of the exponential function on the last term that involves the face value.

Comment: @xyz For the face value term, probably you mean $+Fe^{-(T-t)r}$. The coupon terms work for integer $t$ and consider the price just after the coupon is paid.

Comment: Yes, as for the face value term, that's what I meant. I understand that this expression only works for integer $t$ (that's why I specified that the coupon must be paid anually and not semi-anually or any other way). Thank you for your help, very useful.

Comment: @xyz Yes the coupon is paid annually here, but it's a valid question to ask what the price of the bond is after half year.

Comment: Very nice point (once again). Let's say I am asked to calculate the prince of a bond after half an year in the same conditions of my first comment to your answer: would there be any difference between this and the initial value? In other words, I believe that $B_c(0) = B_c(0.5)$ and in the same logic I believe that $B_c(1) = B_c(1.5)$, etc. (again, in the same conditions of my first comment). Is this logic correct?

Comment: @xyz No, because at $t=0.5$, the coupons are now only $0.5,1.5,2.5,\ldots,4.5$ years in the future. For example the next coupon now has PV of $ce^{-0.5r}$.

Comment: Thanks once again Peter. I have made a new question regarding FM, if you wish to have a look: (it is related to this question in some sense) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4807805/comparing-a-coupon-bond-with-a-zero-coupon-bond-a-specific-fm-exericse